# Java parser time issue

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am writing a Java parser that get ASANA APP data from ASANA server and parse it and then save it to local DB for customized reports. I have issue with the time needed to execute this Java utility.

I have this sub part of the Java parser. When I run this, it takes approximately 10 seconds to execute. If this code executes in 10 sec than one line this is given below:

```
JSONObject Project_jsonObject = (JSONObject) Project_jsonParser.parse(Project_br);
```

This line execute in 9 seconds out of total 10 seconds. How I can reduce this time. Any technique or tip or alternate to reduce time.Please help me I am waiting

```
        static File workDir = new File("C:/cygwin64/bin");
        static Runtime systemShell = Runtime.getRuntime();

        String project_request="curl -u 4cKDgv4O.L8Th7N8l7jADg3HRU44abmT: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/"+id_Project+"?opt_pretty";
        String project_cmd = project_request;
        project_cmd += " | grep 'OBJECT'"; 
        Process ProjectshellOutput = systemShell.exec(workDir+"/"+project_cmd, null,workDir);
        InputStreamReader Project_isr = new InputStreamReader(ProjectshellOutput.getInputStream()); 
        BufferedReader Project_br = new BufferedReader (Project_isr);

        JSONParser Project_jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject Project_jsonObject = (JSONObject) Project_jsonParser.parse(Project_br);

        JSONObject projectdataObject= (JSONObject)Project_jsonObject.get("data");

        Long project_id =  (Long) projectdataObject.get("id");
        System.out.println("project id is: " + project_id);


        String project_created_at_dt = (String) projectdataObject.get("created_at");
        System.out.println("The project created at is: " + project_created_at_dt);

        String project_modified_at_dt = (String) projectdataObject.get("modified_at");
        System.out.println("The project modified at is: " + project_modified_at_dt);

        boolean project_public_status = (boolean) projectdataObject.get("public");
        System.out.println("project public status: " + project_public_status);

        String project_name = (String) projectdataObject.get("name");
        System.out.println("project name is: " + project_name);

        String project_notes = (String) projectdataObject.get("notes");
        System.out.println("project Notes are: " + project_notes);

        boolean project_archived_status = (boolean) projectdataObject.get("archived");
        System.out.println("project archived status: " + project_archived_status);

        JSONObject workspaceObj = (JSONObject) projectdataObject.get("workspace");
        Long workspace_id = (Long) workspaceObj.get("id");
        String workspace_name = (String) workspaceObj.get("name");
        System.out.println("Workspace id " + workspace_id + " with workspace  name " + workspace_name);


        String color = (String) projectdataObject.get("color");
        System.out.println("color : " + color);

        JSONObject teamObj = (JSONObject) projectdataObject.get("team");
        Long team_id = (Long) teamObj.get("id");
        String team_name = (String) teamObj.get("name");
        System.out.println("team id " + team_id + " with team name " + team_name);
```

Comment: Your code will be easier to read if you follow these conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Exactly what is a `JSONParser`?

Comment: Why `opt_pretty`? This is a waste here. Also, you want to use Jackson instead of org.json for such stuff

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede looks like he's trying to write his own REST client, rather than just use Jersey and Jackson or Gson. Most likely the delays he's experiencing have everything to do with slow network traffic and web services, and nothing with his own code.

Comment: @jwenting Well, I'm assuming he's actually correct that the `parse(...)` method is what's taking so long.  Maybe that's assuming too much.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede he says the parse() executes at 9 seconds out of 10 seconds total. Only thing that could cause such delay is his system exec call to curl, which is the http request to get the json from an external sourse.

Comment: @fge. I use org.json because I am working with small database (15 mb database file) and jackson is not good option for small data files. Jackson is best to parse big json files.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede System is not delaying at exec call to curl. Within 1 sec exec is executed but JSONObject Project_jsonObject = (JSONObject) Project_jsonParser.parse(Project_br); this line need 90% time to execute

Comment: So what is a `JSONParser`?  Are you using json-simple?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes i am using json-simple

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede  JSONParser is used to get json elements in java objects, arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the JSON.simple library.  According to [this test](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/), JSON.simple parsed a 190 MB file in about 140 seconds.  That's in line with taking 9 seconds to parse a 15 MB file.  Jackson is faster, but only just barely.  So I doubt there's anything you can do to significantly improve performance.

Comment: @abdul_majid_bajwa001 There is no reason to think that there is a problem to be solved.

Comment: is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: @abdul_majid_bajwa001 There's a parser called [Boon](https://github.com/boonproject/boon/wiki/Boon-JSON-in-five-minutes) that claims to be much faster.  But you may rewrite your entire program and then find it's not faster for your use case.